# Using an apostrophe inside a query

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

So using prepared statements im trying to query with a '

i have a string called $awayteam wich holds : SSS'18 VR1

When i try to query the DB with above string it wont work....

```
$conn = new PDO($link, $pdo_username, $pdo_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clublogo WHERE naam = :name");
//$stmt->bindParam(':name', $awayteam);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $awayteam, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
$awayclublogo = sprintf($row[pad]);

}
$conn = null;
```

$awayclublogo will be NULL

However when i do it with just TEXT it does work.

```
$conn = new PDO($link, $pdo_username, $pdo_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clublogo WHERE naam = :name");
$stmt->bindValue(':name',  "SSS'18 VR1");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
$awayclublogo = sprintf($row[pad]);

}
$conn = null;
```

OK So @Devon pointed out that the problem was due to HTML encoding. 
Told me to look at the source, and sure he was right.
SSS'18 VR

im getting the variable from the DB like :

```
$conn = new PDO($link, $pdo_username, $pdo_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM vrip_uitslag WHERE GameID =     :name");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $gameid);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();


foreach($result as $row) { 
$hometeam = sprintf($row[Thuis]);
$awayteam = sprintf($row[Uit]);
}
```

var_dump($awayteam) will result : string(15) "SSS'18 VR1"
i then use $awayteam so i have no clue where the HTML encoding is happening....

Comment: just escape that special character

Comment: I would think that would work but you're better off using a prepared query any way then you wont have to worry about specific characters or malicious users. This thread is on the safety side but shows how to use prepared statements, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: i know about prepared statements, i do use them, also here, this is just for short write on here :)

Comment: @BeingSunny How do i escape it? i tried a str replace and then feed the query but that doesnt work either...

Comment: @defiancenl... if you do use prepared statements, you wouldn't have to escape it...

Comment: What exactly is `$conn`? If you are using mysqli then look into [`$mysqli->real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @Devon $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT * clublogo WHERE name = ? ');

$sth->execute(array($awayteam));

$red = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($red);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's been established that this is solved using prepared statements since you're using PHP.  This would handle this automatically.

In SQL in general, you can escape it in a couple ways:

Use another apostrophe (single quote) before it:

```
'SSS''18 VR1'
```

Use the backslash before it:

```
'SSS\'18 VR1'
```

Comment: Hi Devon, i tried prepared but this is what happened ...... $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT * clublogo WHERE name = ? ');

$sth->execute(array($awayteam));

$red = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($red);  $red is empty .....

Comment: I cannot edit it for now, since it comes from another website

Comment: The error is you don't have a `FROM`. before `clublogo`

Answer (score 0):

Double up on single quotes. Add an extra single quote to escape it.

```
SELECT * FROM clublogo WHERE name = 'SSS''18 VR1'
```

Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) if you are using PDO.

```
$dbh = new PDO("...");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM clublogo WHERE name = :name");
$stmt->bindValue(':name',  "SSS'18 VR1");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

You have to use [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) if you are using a variable.

```
$dbh = new PDO("...");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM clublogo WHERE name = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $awayteam, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$awayteam = "SSS'18 VR1";
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

PDO: [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: When i try this it works... however when i replace "SSS'18 VR1" with $awayteam (wich has SSS'18 VR1) it wont work...

Comment: You have to use bindParam instead of bindVaram if you are using a variable. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Try this: $stmt->bindParam(':name', $awayteam, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: Still results in NULL :/

Comment: @defiancenl, what is the actual value of $awayteam?  and what is actually stored in the database?  Print out $awayteam, and don't look at the HTML print out, look at the source.

Comment: From your earlier comment, I'm fairly certain you have it html encoded for some reason.

Comment: @defiancenl well, look at your code and figure out if you're running htmlentitites on it, if you're retrieving the value like this, then you could run http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: @SaiKiranSripada, these functions won't decode single quotes by default.  You need the correct flag.

Comment: @Devon take a look at the edit, i have no clue where the html encode is happening.... the ' is like ' in the DB. not html encoded

Comment: Search your code base for 'htmlentitites' or 'htmlspecialchars'.  I think this has exploded beyond the scope of the original question by now.   P.S.  I don't see why you need to use sprintf(), but that wouldn't cause the issue.